# Select Rows by Consecutive Dates in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table with data like below:

Log Table:

| User Id | Login Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 |
| 1 | 2022-01-10 |
| 1 | 2022-01-11 |
| 1 | 2022-01-12 |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 |
| 1 | 2022-01-25 |
| 1 | 2022-01-26 |
| 1 | 2022-01-27 |
| 1 | 2022-01-28 |

What I'm trying to do is to create a query that return rows of the latest logins by consecutive dates with var_date as parameter.

If var_date is 2022-01-29, then the result is:

| User Id | Login Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-25 |
| 1 | 2022-01-26 |
| 1 | 2022-01-27 |
| 1 | 2022-01-28 |

If var_date is 2022-01-30, then no result is returned, since 2022-01-29 is not in the table.

If var_date is 2022-01-24, then the query will return row with 2022-01-23 as login date.

How am I to do this in SQLite?

Thank you.

Comment: @forpas Hi. The result was as expected. But because of some minor changes, I made some modifications using the answer as code base. I could ask for alteration based on the changes but it felt lazy. Sorry if it caused misunderstanding.

Comment: Did yo also feel lazy to read and try other answers with simpler code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a variant of gaps and islands, with the islands being clusters of records per user with continuous dates.  Here is one approach using analytic functions:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN julianday(LoginDate) -
              julianday(LAG(LoginDate) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID
                                             ORDER BY LoginDate))
                  > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS counter
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(counter) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY LoginDate) AS grp
    FROM cte
)

SELECT UserID, LoginDate
FROM cte2 t1
WHERE LoginDate < '2022-01-29' AND
      grp = (SELECT t2.grp FROM cte2 t2
             WHERE t2.UserID = t1.UserID AND t2.LoginDate = '2022-01-28');
```

### Demo

The two CTEs generate a pseudo date group for each cluster per user.  The final query returns all records less than the target date for which the group value is the same as the immediately preceding date.  Hence, for dates having no immediate record for a given user, the query will return empty set.

Comment: I have to alter the code because of some minor requirement changes, but it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte(UserId, LoginDate) AS (
  SELECT :var_user_id, :var_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT UserId, date(c.LoginDate, '-1 day')
  FROM cte c
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename t WHERE t.UserId = c.UserId AND t.LoginDate = date(c.LoginDate, '-1 day'))
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE LoginDate < (SELECT MAX(LoginDate) FROM cte);
```

Change `:var_user_id` and `:var_date` to the values that you want for the user's id and the date.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=efe8177e93a8e9f535970f5725b88ea5).